# Add a list of empty columns with specific names to a list of df in R

Tags: r

I have a list of 10 df in R with 2 columns and I want to add 5 empty columns to each df in the list. The columns have specific names. I imported the df as a list using a for loop.

```
temp_file = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
my_data <- list()
for (i in seq_along(temp_file)) {
my_data[[i]] <- read.csv(file = temp_file[i])}
```

So now I have a list of df with 2 columns as below

| col_A | col_B |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | abc |
| 16 | 78 |
| xyz | 295 |

I have a string called new_columns

`new_columns <- c("col_C", "col_D", "col_E", "col_xg", "col_W93")`

I want to add these 5 empty columns to all the 10 data frames in the list **my_data**

I tried a for loop and rbind but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop over the `list` ('my_data'), assign those columns ('new_columns') to blank and return the dataset

```
my_data <- lapply(my_data, function(x) {x[new_columns] <- ''; x})
```

Comment: In my list, 8 df have the 2 columns I mentioned and 2 df have all the 7 columns I want. Is there a way to add an if statement or something similar that states that if colNums == 2, then add the new_columns?

Comment: We can modify the code to `my_data <- lapply(my_data, function(x) x[setdiff(new_columns, names(x))] <- ''; x})`

Comment: @Kriti i guess it should work assuming that these column names are same in all dataset

Comment: I get this error - Error: unexpected ';' in "my_data <- lapply(my_data, function(x) x[setdiff(new_columns, names(x))] <- '';"

Comment: @Kriti Sorry, The `{` was missed.  Can you add those `my_data <- lapply(my_data, function(x) {x[setdiff(new_columns, names(x))] <- ''; x})`

Comment: Not at all! You have been really helpful. Sorry, I have a query about this. This goes on and adds the empty new_columns to all df. So now I have 2 with 12 columns and the remaining with 7 columns. I want the code to check if the existing column numbers are 7 then it shouldn't add any columns at all.

Comment: @Kriti The code was kind of checking if the column name of the dataset is already present in 'new_columns' names and only those names that are not there is added.  Maybe your dataset have different columns names.  In that case, do `my_data <- lapply(my_data, function(x) {if(ncol(x) == 2) {x[new_column] <- ''}; x})`